# SQL query to select matrix user-day count

Tags: sql, database

I have the next data

| User | Day |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | Monday |
| User2 | Monday |
| User3 | Monday |
| User2 | Tuesday |
| User3 | Tuesday |

I'm looking for a query that will produce the next result

| User | Monday | Tuesday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 1 | 0 |
| User2 | 1 | 1 |
| User3 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

I use a conditional aggregation approach better than a PIVOT one, because I feel its syntax is less complicated and it is less limited (and eficiency is not worse).

```
select [User],
  SUM(case when Day = 'Monday' then 1 else 0 end) Monday,
  SUM(case when Day = 'Tuesday' then 1 else 0 end) Tuesday
from YourTable
group by [User]
```

By the way, you should not use `User` as a field name, because it is a reserved word.

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1f7d06eaa4ac8f23498a71ff552a6a4f

Answer (score 1):

You can use pivot like below;

```
WITH q AS (
  SELECT  aUser = 'User1', aDay = 'mon', aCount = 1
  UNION ALL   SELECT 'User1','mon',1
  UNION ALL   SELECT 'User1','mon',1
  UNION ALL   SELECT 'User2','mon',1
  UNION ALL   SELECT 'User3','tue',1
  UNION ALL   SELECT 'User2','wed',1
  UNION ALL   SELECT 'User3','thu',1
  UNION ALL   SELECT 'User2','thu',1
  UNION ALL   SELECT 'User2','thu',1
  UNION ALL   SELECT 'User2','mon',1
)
SELECT  aUser
        , mon = ISNULL(mon,0)
        , tue = ISNULL(tue,0)
        , wed = ISNULL(wed,0)
        , thu = ISNULL(thu,0)
        , fri = ISNULL(fri,0)
        , sat = ISNULL(sat,0)
        , sun = ISNULL(sun,0)
FROM    (
          SELECT  *
          FROM    q
        ) s
PIVOT   (sum(aCount) FOR aDay IN (mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun)) pvt
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use PIVOT to change rows with columns:

for just these two days:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT [day], [user]
    FROM table1
) as s
PIVOT
(
    count([day])
    FOR [day] IN (Monday, Tuesday)
)AS pvt
```

for all days of the week:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT [day], [user]
    FROM table1
) as s
PIVOT
(
    count([day])
    FOR [day] IN (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday)
)AS pvt
```